# Did Captain Kirk ever lose a fight when his shirt ripped?

Tags: star-trek, captain-kirk

Apparently, James Kirk's fighting skills increased after his shirt ripped, or maybe it was a coincidence that he never seemed to lose when this occurred. Am I just remembering incorrectly, or did Kirk really have an undefeated record when his shirt ripped?

Comment: I think if you just limit your question to "Did Captain Kirk ever lose a fight?"  you will find the answer is "Not according to Kirk"...Thus the answer is also he never lost a fight when he ripped his shirt either

Comment: Why is it interesting to know if there's a correlation between Kirk's win/loss record and his shirt being ripped?  In any case, unless you're going to split hairs, his shirt was sliced open and he _died_ in "Amok Time," so yes, you're remembering incorrectly.

Comment: Because I'm curious. Just because you don't find it interesting, doesn't mean that everybody does.

Comment: You're right, some people might find it interesting, but I know I'm not the only one who doesn't like this sort of question.  I'm going to start using a boilerplate comment for them in the future...

Comment: Your question seems to be about a trivial detail; it's not clear how it leads to a greater understanding of any aspect of the work(s) in question.  You may get a more positive response if you can explain why it's interesting or how it's relevant.

Comment: I guess sometimes it's just fun to ask a fun question. I'm not sure why everything has to be so serious all the time on this site. Technically, I could say that I don't find any of your questions interesting or believe that they're trivial; it's rather subjective, I think.

Comment: There's a "How many females has Captain Kirk slept with?" question. That seems fairly trivial, almost just for laughs, and yet nobody seems to have a problem with that question.

Comment: @T-1000 Kirk was characterized as a womanizer throughout the series, it's a core part of his personality.  (Aside, it was asked 3 times; the one with the exact wording in your comment was closed as a duplicate)

Comment: Actually, I see merit in this question. An alien is often shown to be powerful by having them fight Worf and win. I think it's interesting to know if the ripped shirt is used in a similar manner, to signal that "now it's serious".

Comment: @SQB Thanks, now I wonder what would have happened, if Worf would have had to fight Kirk in *Generations*...

Comment: I'd like to suggest, (pre-experimentation), the hypothesis that Kirk's Ripped Shirt (TM) grants him +5000 Defense, with various Resistances including Space Magic, Alien Classic Literature, Vague Energy Weapons, Crisis Situations, Extraterrestrial Wrestling, Seductive Women, and Hostile Prosthetic Expressions. This hypothesis warrants investigation...

Comment: Also Subversive Empathy and Computer Logic, to name a couple more... Perhaps it was the rip that granted these bonuses or perhaps it was the shirt...

Answer (score 4):

Captain Kirk got his butt kicked by Leela in *Where No Fan Has Gone Before*, despite his shirt being ripped. Also, Spock messed him up in both *Amok Time* and *The Paradise Syndrome*. It would be difficult to believe that having half a bridge fall on him in *Star Trek: Generations* didn't rip his shirt, but it isn't visibly torn.

If you include books, Omnidon beats Kirk to a pulp on multiple occasions in *The Flight of the Phoenix* and *The Fate of the Phoenix*. I'm sure there are many other examples outside of television and films, but I don't recall any others.

Comment: If I recall, did Kirk not rip his OWN shirt for the purpose of fighting in that Futurama episode? If he did, perhaps he also sees a correlation between winning and shirt-ripping.

Comment: @MacCooper: It's played for laughs, as if he doesn't know how to fight without his shirt ripped. "Wasn't there an episode where I threw my shoe at the enemy?" "My foot's cold."

Comment: haha yeah that was my point :P

Comment: His ripped shirt clearly has Weakness against both Satire and Copper-based Friendship

Answer (score 3):

As per my comment, no, Kirk did not always win fights when his shirt ripped.  "Amok Time" is one counter-example.

Comment: McCoy cheated and doped him up to make him die.

Comment: Arguably, since Kirk did not actually die, and Spock ended up returning to the Enterprise, you could say Kirk lost the battle, but won the war.